# How to read previous values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where the IDs , Reference IDs and amounts are stored. The problem is that for the rows where reference IDs is set the amount is missing. I need to read the rows where reference_id = ID and read the amount and set the value  (like it is shown in Table2).

```
+--+------------+------+
|ID|Reference ID|Amount|
+--+------------+------+
|1 |            |300   |
+--+------------+------+
|2 |1           |      |
+--+------------+------+
```

I want to be able to show:
Table 2

```
+--+------------+------+
|ID|Reference ID|Amount|
+--+------------+------+
|1 |            |300   |
+--+------------+------+
|2 |1           |300   |
+--+------------+------+
```

Anyone has any idea whats the best way to find this missing value?
Best Regards.
MEJ

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a self-join:

```
select t1.id, t1.referenceid, coalesce(t2.amount, t1.amount) as amount
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table1 t2
     on t1.id = t2.referenceid;
```

Comment: In fact i had tried self-join before. It doesn't give me the result i want... what i get using self join is same results as in (Table 1 in my example). I don't know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: @user1495959 . . . Try the version in the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a hierarchical query:

```
select id, ref_id, connect_by_root amount
from <your table>
connect by prior id = ref_id
start with ref_id is null;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27e21/1).

More about the [`connect_by_root` operator in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/operators004.htm).

This [allows for multiple levels](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/386ba/2) since it always goes back to the root for the `amount`. But that kind of assumes that the child records never have an `amount` themselves, or it can be ignored. You can use `nvl` to the the child value if it is set, but children of that will still go back to the root. You can add an `amount` null check to the conditions if you want to show the previous value:

```
select id, ref_id, connect_by_root amount as amount
from <your table>
connect by prior id = ref_id and amount is null
start with ref_id is null or amount is not null
order by id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/316ff8/1).